# Ajax how change value id to text database?

Tags: ajax, laravel, database, xampp, laravel-8

I have a problem that is the value displayed in the database is the id value not the value of the text that appears in the input label. then my question is how to change the id value to a text value?

[image]

route web.php

```
`Route::get('/selectProvinces', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ManagementController::class, 'provinces'])->name('province.index');  `
```

ajax script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#selectProvinces").select2({
            placeholder: 'Pilih Provinsi',
            ajax: {
                url: "{{route('province.index')}}",
                processResults: function ({
                    data
                }) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                id: item.id,
                                text: item.name
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        });

</script>
```

blade.php boostrap

```
<div class="row">
   <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Provinsi</label>
      <div class="col">
          <select id="selectProvinces" class="form-control selectpicker" name="provinces">                            
          </select>
       </div>
</div>
```

controller

```
public function management_create(Request $request) {

    Member::create([
        'provinces'         => $request->provinces,
    ]);

    Alert::success('Success', 'Member berhasil dibuat');
    return redirect()->route('management');
}
```

i hope the value changes text value like "East Java" not the number

Comment: Can you add your controller provinces to your question

Comment: Members::create([
            'provinces'         => $request->provinces,
        ]);    


that is my controller sir

Comment: <div class="row">
                                        <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Provinsi</label>
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <select id="selectProvinces" class="form-control selectpicker "
                                                name="provinces">                            
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

Comment: Can you add this into your question by editing them

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Done sir, can check my problem again?